# Jest can't find component imported in my test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

**My branch:** https://github.com/Futuratum/moonholdings.io/tree/JestTests

I'm using [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) to build my app, and also using TypeScript. So there isn't a Webpack file I edit, Next handles that. Full package.json below.

**My super simple test (no errors in VSCode):**

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

import Astronaut from './Astronaut';

describe('<Astronaut /> component', () => {
  console.log('Astronaut', Astronaut);
  describe('when rendering', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Astronaut {...props} />);

    it('should render a component matching the snapshot', () => {
      const tree = toJson(wrapper);
      expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
      expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    });
  });
});
```

**Folder structure:**

[image]

**The error:**

[image]

**Any thoughts of why it's complaining?**

**My Jest config:**

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.next/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
      ".*": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
```

jest.setup.js

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "moonholdings.io",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Moonholdings.io",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next -p 7777",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p 8000",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test jest --watch",
    "test-win": "SET NODE_ENV=test&& jest --watch",
    "heroku-postbuild": "next build"
  },
  "author": "Futuratum",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.1.16",
    "apollo-client": "^2.4.2",
    "decko": "^1.2.0",
    "downshift": "^2.2.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.6.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.5.0",
    "graphql": "^14.0.2",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.9.2",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "next": "^7.0.2",
    "next-with-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.11.0",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-adopt": "^0.6.0",
    "react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.4.9",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "waait": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/next": "^7.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/zeit__next-typescript": "^0.1.1",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.7.1",
    "casual": "^1.5.19",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/.next/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.(gql|graphql)$": "jest-transform-graphql",
      ".*": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js?$\\.tx?$\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: By default it'll look for Astronaut.js, what's handling the tsx transpilation?

Comment: Does it work when you add `.tsx`?

Comment: @jmargolisvt OH! Maybe that's it, I just added my jest config. What would the syntax be to add `.ts` and `.tsx` into `"^.+\\.js?$": "babel-jest"`?

Comment: I just added `"^.+\\.js?$\\.tx?$\\.tsx?$": "babel-jest"` and changed the test to `Astronaut.test.tsx` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also place the `__tests__` folder in the Astronaut folder and then import Austronaut.tsx into your test as '../Astronaut.tsx'.

Answer (score 0):

Ok for this to work, I needed to move my test into `__tests__` in the root. Then import the component like so:

`import Astronaut from '../components/Astronaut/Astronaut.tsx';`